# NopCommerce: How do I display extra information in the order details page?

Tags: c#, e-commerce, payment-gateway, nopcommerce

I am developing a payment gateway for NopCommerce. I have some extra information (number of installments) that I need to have appear on the Info tab in the Order Details page - in the admin area. Basically, I want to add an extra field somewhere just to show the number of installments which the customer selected to pay.

Does Nop have a way to do this already (adding custom values)? Or do I need to hack it? I don't really want to change the source code in the main projects unless I don't have a choice.

Actually, I have the same requirement for the shopping cart page as well. I need to show some text like, "You can pay in [n] installments". Is there a way I can tell Nop to do that from my payment plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for the shopping cart page, I added a widget and for the number of installments the client was not pleased with the order note idea, so I decided to add it to the authorization ID instead.., as it is just a string.. so now I have it like this (for example):  "Authorization ID:  1234567890  (5 installments)" and that's kept my client happy.

Answer (score 2):

Actually for simplicity you can use order notes or admin comment if you just want to add some simple information. I would go for order notes in this case.

For your second requirement, there's the 'payment info' step during checkout, so you can display any message you want during this step.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I will look into the first thing. For the second one, I already have the info in payment info step, but my customer wants the info to be in the shopping cart as well.

Comment: You can make your the same plugin a Widget plugin as well, then set the WidgetZone for your plugin to be any zone displayed in the shopping cart. For example "order_summary_content_before" is a good zone to put content in, but you can freely select any other zone. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using instance of IGenericAttributeService.

**Insert**

```
_genericAttributeService.SaveAttribute(customer, "CustomFieldName", "CustomValue");
```

**Select**

```
var customValue = customer.GetAttribute<string>("CustomFieldName");
```

Take a look at the Register post action of CustomerController.